# problem The application could not be installed: INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_MANIFEST_MALFORMED android 24?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, manifest

> Hello guys
>  I know that this problem is old and its causes are
> many. I went through all the links and saw solutions, all of which did
> not work:
>  **The problem only appears on Android 21 to 24**.
>  **It
> works on 27 and above**.
>  In addition, I exported a file APK final
> with the key, and copied it to a real Android 24 device. I got a
> message:
>  Failed to parse the package I hope to help

### error message

```
The application could not be installed: INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_MANIFEST_MALFORMED
```

### manifests

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.rifai.azan">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />

    <application
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:name="activities.Signal"
        android:largeHeap="true"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_descriptor">
        <activity
            android:name="activities.SplashScreen_Activity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="activities.Prayers_Activity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="activities.Info_Activity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="activities.Kibla_Activity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="activities.Home_Programe_Activity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="activities.Settings_Activity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" >
        </activity>

        <receiver android:name="widget.SmallWidgetProvider"
            android:icon="@drawable/small_widget"
            android:label="Small Widget">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
                android:resource="@xml/small_widget_provider" />
        </receiver>

        <receiver android:name="widget.SmallWidgetProviderBroadcastReceiver"/>

        <receiver android:name="widget.LargeWidgetProvider"
            android:icon="@drawable/large_widget"
            android:label="Large Widget">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
                android:resource="@xml/large_widget_provider" />
        </receiver>

        <receiver android:name="widget.LargeWidgetProviderBroadcastReceiver"/>

        <receiver
            android:name="classes.StartServiceAtStartupDevice"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="false" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <receiver android:name="classes.AthanServiceBroasdcastReceiver" android:exported="false" />

        <receiver android:name="classes.RefreshWidgetAfter15Minutes" android:exported="false" />

        <service
            android:name="classes.AthanService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true"
            android:permission="android.premssion.BIND_JOb_SERVICE">
        </service>

        <service
            android:name="widget.LargeWidgetProviderService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true"
            android:permission="android.premssion.BIND_JOb_SERVICE">
        </service>

        <service
            android:name="widget.SmallWidgetProviderService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true"
            android:permission="android.premssion.BIND_JOb_SERVICE">
        </service>

        <receiver android:name="classes.RefreshDayServiceManager">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.TIME_SET" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <receiver android:name="Athan.AthanStopReceiver" android:exported="false" >
        </receiver>

    </application>


</manifest>
```

Comment: In AndroidStudio there is a option to see MergedManifest when you open your AndroidManifest.xml. There you can find more information what is real problem, Usually it gives you suggestions how to fix it.

Comment: Where can I find it and how do I use it sir?